# Can't activate conda environment

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I use `Anaconda` frequently to manage python packages on a Windows machine. But I'm having trouble understanding how it works on a Ubuntu, probably because I'm new to Linux in general.

I downloaded the Anaconda Linux installer (python 3) and run `bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` to install. After installation, I was able to type `anaconda-navigator` in terminal to start the GUI, where I created a new python 3.6 environment called `tensorflow_env`. But I couldn't activate it in the terminal. I followed the error message and typed

`echo ". /home/chris/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc`
 in the terminal, which solved the problem.

To validate, here is how it looks like now in my terminal:
[image]

Being a frequent Anaconda user in Windows, what I don't understand is when I clicked `open terminal` from the **green triangle in the GUI** (see screenshot below), 
[image]

The opened conda terminal still says `bash: activate: No such file or directory`. And if I test `Python`, as you can see it's not even python 3.
[image]

What's going on with the navigator? It still can't activate environments.

Comment: I have the very similar error, but in my case anaconda-navigator was working properly and at some point it stoped. I am not exactly sure, but it looks it has something to do with execution of conda init part int  the .bashrc script. When you open a terminal it cannot activate the environemnt and you are still at the host level. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @sebastian unfortunately I did not. i moved on to not relying on conda on my Ubuntu machine. best luck to you my friend